# varnish throwing gzip error

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, cache, varnish

I get this error when running:

varnishlog -b -q 'FetchError'

```
-   ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   ObjHeader      Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   ObjHeader      Content-Language: uk
-   ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
-   Fetch_Body     4 eof -
-   Gzip           Gunzip error: -3 (invalid code lengths set)
-   FetchError     Invalid Gzip data: invalid code lengths set
-   Gzip           G F E 0 20 80 80 90
-   Gzip           U F - 6212 24576 80 0 0
-   BackendClose   23 2bd71e1f-2123-45a8-947a-54f4cd2ae90b.default
-   Timestamp      Error: 1501073397.946314 0.353247 0.000348
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2017 12:49:57 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      503
-   ObjReason      Backend fetch failed
-   ObjHeader      Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2017 12:49:57 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Server: Varnish
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   ObjHeader      Retry-After: 5
-   Length         284
-   BereqAcct      1246 0 1246 1063 0 1063
-   End
```

I have nginx -> varnish -> apache2

The error happens when a website is trying to retrieve content from another server via curl and display it as its own page  - this would be happening in apache and it fails quite a lot with the error above. The site is running wordpress and the problem seems to be caused by the unbounce plugin - other sites on the same server seem to manage ok.

Any thoughts much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have turned off mod_deflate on apache and this seems to have helped - I think we are getting some errors from unbounce which messes up the gzipping - making Varnish deal with this seems to fix it.